# Getting Aggregate Values Grouped By Date from Four Tables Simultaneously

Tags: sql, count, group-by, teradata, outer-join

For a specific downstream reason, I am trying to get aggregate data from four tables in one query (Teradata). I have been able to easily accomplish this by writing subqueries, but unfortunately, I also need the data returned to be grouped by date. Each field has a timestamp attribute (time of transaction), and I am hoping to return a table with the columns: Date, Count1, Count2, Count3, Count4. Ideally each count would have the total number of transactions from that given day, and the count would vary depending on the table.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1) AS COUNT1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2) AS COUNT2, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE3) AS COUNT3, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE4) AS COUNT4,
```

Example answer:

1. 4/11/2015  5    2    7   22
2. 4/12/2015  8    1    0   3

This way I can get counts from all four tables, but I was want to SELECT CAST(Datestamp AS Date) and group by that, while getting the counts for each individual dates. The datestamp attribute is in every table, how do I accomplish this? Do I need to do multiple full outer joins here? I feel like a join might not be necessary but I want to get this down! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using union all to combine all your tables and conditional aggregation to count the # of rows per (date,table) combination:

```
select 
    myDate,
    count(case when n = 1 then 1 end) count1,
    count(case when n = 2 then 1 end) count2,
    count(case when n = 3 then 1 end) count3,
    count(case when n = 4 then 1 end) count4
from (
    select 1 n, cast(Datestamp as Date) myDate from table1
    union all select 2, cast(Datestamp as Date) myDate from table2
    union all select 3, cast(Datestamp as Date) myDate from table3
    union all select 4, cast(Datestamp as Date) myDate from table4
) t 
group by myDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full outer join`.  You can also do this with `union all` and `group by`:

```
select dte, max(t1cnt) as t1cnt, max(t2cnt) as t2cnt,
       max(t3cnt) as t3cnt, max(t4cnt) as t4cnt
from ((select CAST(Datestamp AS Date) as dte, count(*) as t1cnt, 0 as t2cnt, 0 as t3cnt, 0 as t4cnt
       from table1
       group by CAST(Datestamp AS Date)
      ) union all
      (select CAST(Datestamp AS Date) as dte, 0 as t1cnt, count(*) as t2cnt, 0 as t3cnt, 0 as t4cnt
       from table2
       group by CAST(Datestamp AS Date)
      ) union all
      (select CAST(Datestamp AS Date) as dte, 0 as t1cnt, 0 as t2cnt, count(*) as t3cnt, 0 as t4cnt
       from table3
       group by CAST(Datestamp AS Date)
      ) union all
      (select CAST(Datestamp AS Date) as dte, 0 as t1cnt, 0 as t2cnt, 0 as t3cnt, count(*) as t4cnt
       from table4
       group by CAST(Datestamp AS Date)
      ) 
     ) t
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Comment: This logic makes perfect sense, but for some reason it is complaining about the syntax after the last union all. Maybe it's just a teradata thing, because it looks like this should work. Thanks, I assume that the max of Null and 0 would return zero? I'm asking because I need zeroes to show as zeroes, and there will be lots of zeroes for given days/tables.

Comment: @marchocolate . . . I fixed that.  Copy-and-paste detritus.